# Show polyline in android Google Maps exactly like Google Maps app in phone

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I am developing an app where I want to show polyline for multiple routes. I am able to draw polyline using directions API. But I want it look alike Google maps app in my phone. Is there any API or I have to customize polyline colors and options?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Draw Map Route Api. It will help you click [here](https://github.com/ar-android/DrawRouteMaps?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5463)

Comment: I have already done that. But I want to show it like Google maps app that reside in everyone's android phone.